# Dynamic OGP meta tags not working in react js application

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

1. We have implemented OGP meta tags for each page in header.js file which are getting from CMS APIs in React js application.
2. We are able to see the OGP meta tags in header section of application in browser by using Inspect Element option
3. Unable to fetch the 3rd party meta tag tools like https://www.opengraph.xyz/ or https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ tools and not showing in "view source" of page
   We have tried to use react-meta-tags and react-helmet npm packages but no luck

Comment: The meta tags should be visible when viewing your app's page using view-source. If that doesn't work you would need to setup server-side-rendering or static-site-generation for your app. The best way to do that would be to use Next.js, as it provides an easy way to provide meta tags.

Comment: If you're using create-react-app, that doesn't support SSR or SSG out of the box.

Comment: @Shreshth Is there any other way apart from SSR/SSG for create-react-app ?

Comment: @Harry not sure if I follow your question. It would be the easiest to use next.js

Comment: @Shreshth I have a project setup with CRA and I dont want to integrate SSR because it will be too complicated since so much amount of work is already done in it. So is there any other way to get dynamic meta tags working? I pull the meta contents from the API and social sites are not picking it up obviously.

Comment: @Harry, honestly, in my opinion, migrating to next.js would be easier than creating your own "framework" to support the meta tags / SSR, and I don't think you can do this without SSG/SSR. Note: My experience is limited to having used next.js and remix.run, if there's an easier way to do SSR in your existing CRA app I am not aware of it. See if this helps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering